# No route matches [POST] for delete and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, http-delete

I know this question was asked a lot of times, but none of the recipes helped me so far.

I have an application written in Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.0 with following routes.rb:

```
resources :announcements do
end
```

Which generates the following routes:

```
        announcements GET    /announcements(.:format)          announcements#index
                      POST   /announcements(.:format)          announcements#create
     new_announcement GET    /announcements/new(.:format)      announcements#new
    edit_announcement GET    /announcements/:id/edit(.:format) announcements#edit
         announcement GET    /announcements/:id(.:format)      announcements#show
                      PATCH  /announcements/:id(.:format)      announcements#update
                      PUT    /announcements/:id(.:format)      announcements#update
                      DELETE /announcements/:id(.:format)      announcements#destroy
```

Then in HTML I use very simple construct:

```
<%= button_to 'X', announcement, method: :delete %>
```

Which produces the following code:

```
<form method="post" class="button_to" action="/announcements/525c0d28b9fd0171e2000003">
    <div>
         <input type="hidden" value="delete" name="_method">
         <input type="submit" value="X">
         <input type="hidden" value="DR+QjuAG9npqqWRV16Zq0G4Cq3lGpNHY0qjV8LJpUZo=" name="authenticity_token">
    </div>
</form>
```

Everything looks pretty simple, clean and correct. Nevertheless I'm getting "No Route Matches" error. Why?

Comment: button_to 'X', announcement_path, method: :delete

Comment: `//= require jquery_ujs` is included and works fine for "confirm" links

Comment: `announcement_path` does not change absolutely anything comparing to just `announcement`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in missing middleware. I have added

```
config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
```

to `/config/application.rb`

Comment: This post might be a bit old at the time of writing this comment but it helped fix a similar issue I was having. I had created a Rails 5 application in API mode and I was trying to get ActiveAdmin to work with it. Turns out you have to add in back a few middleware components to get that to work, this being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= button_to "Delete", {:controller => :announcements, :action => 'destroy', :id => announcement.id }, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error as before. I think something breaks default route processing, will try to find out what.

Comment: just for checking, use link_to instead of button_to. if the request still goes as POST rather than DELETE then there seems some javascript  issues. Does signout work cause it sends a DELETE request.

Comment: Yes, the same error with link_to. Will investigate for javascript issues.

Answer (score -1):

That's because the routes for those paths need to have `:method => :delete` (delete path) & `:method => :put` (update path). POST won't work for either

As per the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

> In Rails, a resourceful route provides a mapping between HTTP verbs
>   and URLs to controller actions. By convention, each action also maps
>   to particular CRUD operations in a database

You also need to use `announcement_path` for your URL helper

Comment: Yep but it's not being passed. I figured anyone who looks at this (especially newbies) would benefit from seeing that you can't send [POST] links to the delete path in Rails

Comment: It is being passed...you can see it in the generated html. The reason it says POST is because Rails uses an overloaded POST with forms because not all browsers support DELETE.

Comment: Using of `announcement_path` in URL helper does not change generated HTML code.